# display data in list view format after query from databases

Tags: vb6

[image: filter record by department]

I added a filter method which is filter by department by select the combo box options, however, I have no idea about how to push the data into the list after query from database. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub comboDept_Click()
    Dim sQuery As String
    Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oRS_PR As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim sPONO As String
    Dim sPOAmt As String

    combVal = comboDept.List(comboDept.ListIndex)
    If combVal = "EIBU_SALES" Then

        sQuery = "Select PO_No, PO_Requestor, PO_Req_Dept, PO_Status, PO_Approval_M, PO_Approval_GM, PO_Approval_D, PO_HRApproval, VC_No, TH_Sup_Inv, PO_HR_Rmk, PO_Req_Date, PO_SupplierName, PO_OverallAmt from PR_INFO where PO_Req_Dept = '" & combVal & "'"

        oRS_PR.Open sQuery, PRCnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic


    ElseIf comboDept.List(comboDept.ListIndex) = "MCBU_SALES" Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (it's just a hint; you have to adjust the code):

```
' Empty list
myListView.ListItems.Clear

' Add items
While (Not oRS_PR.EOF)
  Set item = myListView.ListItems.Add(, , oRS_PR!FIRST_COLUMN)
  item.SubItems(...) = oRS_PR!SOME_COLUMN
  item.SubItems(...) = oRS_PR!OTHER_COLUMN
  oRS_PR.MoveNext
Wend
```